# Update Rows in batches SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a SQL Server table which is having approximately 900 million rows. It is having an Auto increment Id column. My goal is to update the table by only taking 40000 rows at a time. Like, fetch 1st 40000 rows, generate the records for those by calling an API and update in the table. Next, take the next 40000 rows starting from Id 40001, generate the records and store them in table.

For the process, I'm creating a temp table, inserting 40000 records in the temp table from the target table, processing them and updating in the target table. Again in the next iteration, truncating the temp table, taking the next 40000 rows from the target table and inserting into temp table and processing them.

I need to use the temp table because I want to get the Max Id from the temp table, so that, in the next iteration I can select rows from the target table that is greater than Max Id.

Is there any better process to do it?

Comment: Why not just use a variable and add 40,000 to it each time? If some `UPDATE` statements effect 40,000 rows, and others ~39,987 doesn't really matter. Then you don't need a temporary table at all, you can just use boundaries in the `WHERE`: `UPDATE YT... FROM YourTable YT WHERE YourIDColumn > @ID - 40000 AND YourIDColumn <= @ID`

Comment: Hi @Larnu What if the Max Id present in the table is 75000 where as in the update statement ID Column <= 80000, then, shouldn't the query fail?

Comment: Why would it fail?

Comment: Update what ? Also would a subsidiary table do the job instead?

Comment: Hi @Larnu The performance is a bit better by using a variable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using your ID column to limit the range?

```sql
SELECT TOP (40000)
  *
FROM table
WHERE id > @id
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Then loop through in your code, making the start `id` the last from the prior select.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't a keyword in T-SQL.

Comment: Ah, missed it was T-SQL. Answer updated to match.